Number of periodic map orbits and why in $X_{n+1}\equiv 2 X_{n} \pmod{1}$ $X_0 \in (0,1)$ simulation always ends producing $2^{-2}$,$2^{-1}$,$0$?
Q1:
I'm trying to understand the notion of  "number of periodic map orbits" reading here:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/2xmod1Map.html
For K=1 the case is:
$$X_{n+1}\equiv(K+1) X_{n} \pmod{K}$$
$$ X_{0}=\frac{p_o}{q_o} \in \mathbb{Q}  \space [0,1]$$
What does $N_p$ for prime $p$  exactly indicate ? How can this relation be derived? What is the motivation to study these maps and call them orbits?
$$N_p=\frac{2^p-2}{p}$$
Q2: (edit)
This part of the question is partially answered:
The problem seems to be the accumulated precision problem as @zwim pointed out in his answer
I did some simulations where in all the tests  after around 50 iterations always goes to 1/4 then 1/2 and then 0.
$$X_{n+1}\equiv 2 X_{n} \pmod{1}$$
What is going on?  For a given precision N will it always end as :
$$2^{-2},2^{-1},0$$
i.e: $X_o=0.1$ the cycle has to be periodic as 0.2,0.4,0.8,06,0.2...
But in simulation's step 30 jumps from 0.2 to 0.40000001 and there the binary shifting caused by the iteration seems to always end up with the same 3 last numbers, after it goes to constant 0.
Simulation details
The simulations used double-precision IEEE 754:
$$(-1)^{\text{sign}}(1.b_{51}b_{50}\ldots b_0)_2 \times 2^{e-1023}$$
$$(-1)^{\text{sign}}\left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{52} b_{52-i}2^{-i}\right) \times 2^{e-1023}$$
$$2^{−53} ≈ 1.11 × 10{-16}$$
So we can manage around 15 significant digits.
Trick found to significantly extend the numbers of iterations where a "almost-periodicity" is sustained.
I can't exactly explain why this works but:
Adding a $\delta=\alpha \space 10^{-15}$ works as a hack and maintains the "almost-periodicity" for a much larger number of iterations:
$$X_{n+1}\equiv (2+\delta) X_{n} \pmod{1}$$
Example for $X_{0}\approx \varphi - 1$ without $\delta$

Same example adding the $\delta$ :



Are you sure about your simulations ? If you take $x=0.1$ then it'll cycle indefinitely  $0.2,0.4,0.8,0.6;\cdots$. Tried for $\phi-1$ and it was still "random" after 500 iterations.

The problem is the accumulated round-off errors in the simulations, around 50 iterations breaks. For $X_o=0.1$ the cycle is as you say until from 0.2 jumps to 0.40000001 in step 30

One possible explanation to this would be limitless binary representation in memory of floating numbers for computers:
i.e. $x=\sum\limits_{k=1}^N x_k2^{-k}$ where $x_k\in\{0,1\}$ and $N$ is the precision.
Note that the operation $X_{n+1}=\{2X_n\}$ operates a reduction on binary development, it eliminates the first $x_k$ in the summation:
$2x=\sum\limits_{k=1}^N x_k2^{1-k}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} x_{k+1}2^{-k}=x_1+\underbrace{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N-1} x_{k+1}2^{-k}}_{<1}$
Taking the $\pmod 1$ or fractional part eliminates $x_1$ (since its value is $0$ or $1$, $\{x_1\}=0$), and the rest is less than $1$ so it equals its fractional part.
Therefore $\{2x\}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N-1} x_{k+1}2^{-k}$
Next time you'll apply the operation $x_2$ will be eliminated, then $x_3$ and so on, until you are left with $0$.
Written differently $\overline{x_1x_2x_3\cdots x_N}\,\mapsto\, \overline{x_2x_3x_4\cdots x_{N-1}}$
Note:
This is only an approximative explanation because numbers are most likely represented $x=M\,2^{-p}$ where $M$ is an integer and $p$ the precision. So it will not operate exactly as I described above, might be a little more subtle, but probably the error correction will suffer this fate.

I've red your answer again and the wolfram article links, and I realize your answer has all the tools I need to go to the next step and properly understanding the $N_p$ for prime p by myself. Thank you. I'll accept this answer.

I'm glad it helped.

I edited the answer to changhe $x_i$ by $x_k$ in the summation expressions

$$(-1)^{\text{sign}}(1.b_{51}b_{50}\ldots b_0)_2 \times 2^{e-1023}$$
$$(-1)^{\text{sign}}\left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{52} b_{52-i}2^{-i}\right) \times 2^{e-1023}$$
This explains why after around 50 iterations . Also this has the MSB and the LSB in the right order
